# Qt window reopens after being closed

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I created a button to browse data from PC (open PC file and browse). The window opens for the first time normally, then when I close it the window opens again.

What should I do?

Code:

```
class second (QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(second,self).__init__()
        loadUi("tt3.ui",self)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton2_handler)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton2_open) #1

    def pushButton2_handler(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        self.pushButton2_open()

    def pushButton2_open(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        path = filename[0]
        print(path)
  
        try:
            with open(path,"r") as f :
                print(f.readline())
        except IOError:
            print('file not found')
        else :
            print('file is readed')
```

Comment: mmmm, your question is unclear,also provide a [mre]

Comment: Why do you connect two slots to `pushButton2.clicked`? Isn't it obvious that that will call `pushButton2_open` twice?

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks your note solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should delete this row

"""self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton2_open) #1"""